# When I try open web-site page i have an a 'NoReverseMatch' error, how I can fix it?

Tags: python, django

When I try to open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/` I get the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /blog/ Reverse for 'BlogList' with arguments
>   '('test-post',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/$']

**Main urls:**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls', namespace='shop')),
    ...
]\
```

**App urls:**

```
                  url(r'^$', views.blog_list, name='BlogList'),
                  url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\W]+)/$', views.blog_detail, name='BlogDetail'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def blog_list(request):
    template = 'blog/blog.html'
    posts = Post.objects.filter(available=True)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 9)
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'page': page
    }
    return render(request, template, context)


def blog_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, available=True)
    template = 'blog/detail.html'
    return render_to_response(template, {'post': post})
```

**models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated']
        index_together = [
            ['id', 'slug']
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:BlogList', args=[self.slug])
```

Comment: check all urls in your template show your template.

Comment: The problem might be in `blog/blog.html'`, which you haven't shown. The error shows `test-post`, but you don't have any URL patterns with that name in your `urls.py`. As an aside, there are several out of date things in your code, e.g. `url()` instead of `path()`, and `render_to_response` instead of `render`. If you are following a tutorial or book, it looks like it's out of date, so I would recommend looking for a more recent resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your detail view is BlogDetail, not BlogList.

```
   return reverse('blog:BlogDetail', args=[self.slug])
```